# Select a specific column in a DF and a random column (python3, pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to select a column at index 1 and then one random column between the index of 2 and 5.  This code works in selecting a random column:

```
train_cols = train.columns[[random.sample(range(2, 5), 1)]]
```

But when I try to add the "constant" column at index 1 it doesn't work

```
train_cols = train.columns[1,[random.sample(range(2, 5), 1)]]
```

Any help would be great!  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `train.columns` is basically a 1-dimensional numpy array, so you should take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.

Let's take this array as an example:

```
In [2]: x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

(1) Indexing with an integer returns the element at that location:

```
In [3]: x[3]
Out[3]: 'd'
```

(2) Indexing with a list returns the array of values at the given locations:

```
In [4]: x[[3, 5]]
Out[4]: 
array(['d', 'f'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

(3) Indexing with more than one value *not* in a list is used for multi-dimensional arrays, so it won't work in our case:

```
In [5]: x[3, 5]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-37ec23c8a033> in <module>()
----> 1 x[3, 5]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Now, `random.sample` returns a list, so your first command above is doing something like this:

```
In [6]: x[[[2]]]
Out[6]: 
array(['c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

But your second command will do something like `x[1, [[2]]]`, which won't work for the same reason #3 above doesn't work.

What you want is something like `x[[1, 2]]`, and the best way to get that would be this:

```
In[7]: x[[1, random.randint(2, 4)]]
```

which will work because `random.randint` returns an integer and not a list.

Comment: That makes total sense and thank you for the explanation -- I was wondering about generalizing this to other projects and whether this would work if I wanted to select more than one random column (train_cols = random.sample(range(2, 5), 2)

Comment: In that case you could use `x[[1] + random.sample(range(2, 5), 2)]`, where the plus sign concatenates the two lists.

Comment: Wish I could give you several upvotes for how simple and straightforward this solution was.

Answer (score 1):

Let `a` be:

```
a = random.sample(range(2, 5), 1)
```

Since `a` is a list, I would just do this trick to make it work:

```
train_cols = train.columns[[1,a[0]]]
```

Comment: This works for one column but is there any way to have this work for multiple columns if say, train_cols = random.sample(range(2, 5), 2)